# How to compile solidity code in Kali Linux

Tags: solidity, blockchain, linux, npm, debian

I have tried to install the remix IDE for compile my codes in solidity, since for some reason the remix IDE don't open online. I executed the codes bellow and give that errors. Sorry anything grammatical errors, i am Brazilian and haven't domain of the English idiom.

This error happen every time execute 'npm start' for open remix IDE offline.
I'm despaired because of this, anything help is welcome!

#### EXECUTED THAT CODES IN BASH

```
git clone https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide.git  
git clone https://github.com/ethereum/remix.git

cd remix  
npm install  
npm run bootstrap

cd remix-ide  
npm install  
npm run setupremix  
npm start
```

#### AND OBTAINED THAT ERRORS

```
[serve   ] [Fri Jun 21 2019 23:21:29 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00)] "GET /build/app.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"  
[serve   ] [Fri Jun 21 2019 23:21:29 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00)] "GET /build/app.js" Error (404): "Not found"  
[serve   ] [Fri Jun 21 2019 23:21:29 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00)] "GET /favicon.ico" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"  
[serve   ] [Fri Jun 21 2019 23:21:29 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00)] "GET /favicon.ico" Error (404): "Not found"  
[serve   ] [Fri Jun 21 2019 23:21:29 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00)] "GET /favicon.ico" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"
```

#### WHEN I TRY OPEN REMIX IDE IN BROWSER IT'S BELLOW HAPPEN

[image]

Yes, without anything in screen...

Comment: Hi, you can install the solc compiler (https://www.npmjs.com/package/solc) instead of installing remix to compile your code.

Comment: Check the javascript console for errors.